# Renaming all the excel files as per the list in DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

I have approximately 300 files which are to be renamed as per the excel sheet mentioned below[image: excel_sheet]

The folder looks something like this :

[image]

I have tried writing following code, I think there will be a need of looping aswell. But it is not able to rename even one file. Any clue how this can be corrected.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
os.path.abspath('C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop')
master=pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\Test_folder\\master.xlsx')

master['old']=
('C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\Test_folder\\'+master['oldname']+'.xlsx')
master['new']=
('C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\Test_folder\\'+master['newname']+'.xlsx')

newmaster=master[['old','new']]

os.rename(newmaster['old'],newmaster['new'])
```

Comment: Can you post any errors or stacktraces that show up?

Answer (score 1):

Load stuff.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

master = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\Test_folder\\master.xlsx')
```

Set your current directory to the folder.

```
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\Test_folder\\')
```

Rename things one at a time. While it would be cool, `os.rename` is not designed to work with pandas.

```
for row in master.iterrows():
    oldname, newname = row[1]
    os.rename(oldname+'.xlsx', newname+'.xlsx')
```

Comment: Bang On! I thought i was tooo tooo far away from this solution. Thanks a tonn.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are passing two pandas Series into `os.rename()` which expects two strings. Consider passing each Series values elementwise using `apply()`. And use the os-agnostic, `os.path.join` to concatenate folder and file names:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

cd = r'C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Test_folder'

master = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(cd, 'master.xlsx'))

def change_names(row):
    os.rename(os.path.join(cd, row[0] +'.xlsx'), os.path.join(cd, row[1] +'.xlsx'))

master[['oldname', 'newname']].apply(change_names, axis=1)
```